# How can I use Pandas to get data from min&max Date to new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi i'm  looking for possible way to use pandas to select data from min(pre) and max(pos) date of each group ( USERNAME) and reshape them back to the column.
I'm able to get min/max of the group from 'groupby' but still unable to figure out how can i put them back in to column

thanks a for all advices

here is the example datatable...

```
Username log_date         Score
AA       20211227020024   8
BB       20211227020024   26
CC       20211227020024   78
DD       20220122153004   12
AA       20220122153004   13
CC       20220122153004   0
AA       20220122153004   12
BB       20220124002736   10
CC       20220124002736   17
```

and here is the expected output..

```
USERNAME Pre_Date       Pos_Date        Pre     Pos
AA       20211227020024 20220122153004  8       12
BB       20211227020024 20220124002736  26      10
CC       20211227020024 20220124002736  78      17
DD       20220122153004 -               12      0
```

***Add more information on my question...
I want is to get the score from min/max log date.
ex. for user CC there are 3 rows of data in log_date

```
[min] 20211227020024 : 78   
      20220122153004 : 0   
[max] 20220124002736 : 17
```

78 will be my 'Pre' data and 17 will be my 'Pos' data.

is that's means i need to group username column
then get index of the max['log_date'] of the group
then getting the score from that index ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```
df = df.groupby('Username').agg({'log_date': ['min', 'max'], 'Score': ['min', 'max']})
df.columns = ["_".join(x) for x in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
```

O/P:

```
  Username    log_date_min    log_date_max  Score_min  Score_max
0       AA  20211227020024  20220122153004          8         13
1       BB  20211227020024  20220124002736         10         26
2       CC  20211227020024  20220124002736          0         78
3       DD  20220122153004  20220122153004         12         12
```

Explanation:
Step-1: Perform Groupby on Username column and do aggregation to find out min and Max
Step-2: Update Column names

Comment: Thanks for your comment ... i've add some info on my question.. actually what i want is not the min/max score from 'Score' column but the score that from min/max log_date for each group. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```py
df.groupby('Username').agg((min, max))
```

result:

```
           log_date                         Score
           min              max             min     max
Username                
AA         20211227020024   20220122153004  8       13
BB         20211227020024   20220124002736  10      26
CC         20211227020024   20220124002736  0       78
DD         20220122153004   20220122153004  12      12
```

then you can rename your columns as you wish

Comment: Thanks for your comment ... i've add some info on my question.. actually what i want is not the min/max score from 'Score' column but the score that from min/max log_date row for each group. thanks.